# How to take separate output from two for loops using Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

According to the following program, I used two for loops and take a final result to an ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test2forloop2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //main  
        Test2forloop2 dd=new Test2forloop2();
        ArrayList<Double> result = dd.test();
        System.out.println("result="+result);
    }

    //method
    public ArrayList<Double> test() {
        Double x = null;

        ArrayList<Double> arr1 =  new ArrayList<Double>();
        arr1.add(1.0);
        arr1.add(2.0);
        arr1.add(3.0);
        arr1.add(4.0);
        arr1.add(5.0);

        ArrayList<Double> arr2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        arr2.add(6.0);
        arr2.add(7.0);

        ArrayList<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int j = 0; j < arr1.size(); j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++) {
                x= arr2.get(i) +arr1.get(j);
                result.add(x);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This code give output as,

```
result=[7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 10.0, 10.0, 11.0, 11.0, 12.0]
```

But I need to take it separately like,

```
result=[7.0, 8.0]
result=[8.0, 9.0]
result=[9.0, 10.0]
result=[10.0, 11.0]
result=[11.0, 12.0]
```

What are the changes I need to do in my program?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? You already have the elements stored in different arrays

Comment: I need to take separated output as I show in my question.

Comment: @Emalka Go ahead and try, see where you get stuck (if anywhere) and then ask a question about it.

Comment: it good if you declare and define  arr1 and arr2 in main method. then try

Comment: How do you intend to separate them? And why are you building three `List`(s)?

Comment: Actually this is just a sample of my program. I want to 1st take 1st value from 1st for loop and then all values from 2nd for loop . Then take only these values result output. Then again take 2nd value from 1st for loop  and all values from 2nd for loop. Then take these values result output. Like that continue until 1st for loop end. These outputs I need to use in another process in future. Because of that I need separate results.

Answer (score 1):

> This Code will be able to generate the output what you exactly wants. Hope u got the Result. Happy to help :)

```
ArrayList<Double> result = dd.test();
int i=0;
for(Double obj : result){
    if(i %2 == 0){
       System.out.print("result =[ "+obj +", ");
       i++;
       continue;
     }
 System.out.print(obj +" ]");
 System.out.println("");
 i++;
  }
        System.out.println("result="+result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just for this output it is ok. But, If I want to use this separate output in another method, How can  I call it?  I think just calling this method it is don't give separate results.

Comment: And also I think this is only suitable when 2nd for loop have only 2 values. If it change this is not works. Can I use arr2.size() for i %2 == 0?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it not works . If I add another value for  'arr2.add(8.0);'  it gave output as,              result =[ 7.0, 8.0 ]
result =[ 9.0, 8.0 ]
result =[ 9.0, 10.0 ]
result =[ 9.0, 10.0 ]
result =[ 11.0, 10.0 ]
result =[ 11.0, 12.0 ]
result =[ 11.0, 12.0 ]
. But it should be , result =[7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
result =[8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
result =[9.0, 10.0, 11.0]
result =[10.0, 11.0, 12.0]
result =[11.0, 12.0, 13.0] . I think you got my point. Thank you.

Comment: @ Vikrant Kashyap    I want to 1st take 1st value from 1st for loop and then all values from 2nd for loop . Then take only these values result output. Then again take 2nd value from 1st for loop and all values from 2nd for loop. Then take these values result output. Like that continue until 1st for loop end. These outputs I need to use in another process in future.